# How to use kafka in lua (openresty)?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am using a library in **lua (openresty)** to interact with kafka: [github](https://github.com/doujiang24/lua-resty-kafka).
Readme.md describes SSL support for kafka.
To connect, I use the following code

```
local kafka = producer: new (broker_list, {["producer.type"] = "async", ["ssl"] = true}).
```

How do I initialize **truststore_location**, **keystore_location**, **keystore_password**, **key_password**?
I didn't find an example in the repository and stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

sasl authentication is not supported yet. See https://github.com/doujiang24/lua-resty-kafka/pull/102